# How to tell if Intellij considers a project to be maven or sbt?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I am working on a project that offers both sbt and maven builds.  It is not clear to me which one Intellij is choosing after I asked it to open the project by pointing it to the project root directory.

how can I tell within the project which flavor of build intellij is using?

Comment: I don't believe that IntelliJ makes this decision for you.  What command (or commands) you use to build your project outside of IntelliJ should be the same commands you give *to* IntelliJ.

Comment: @Makoto  There is both a pom.xml and a project/SparkBuild.scala  Either one may be used.  I did not choose one explicitly but instead simply pointed IJ to the root directory.

Comment: Yes, but my point is:  whatever *you* have to use to build the project outside the scope of an IDE should be what you tell your IDE to use to build the project.

Comment: @Makoto  My point is I did *not* specify one or the other. IJ decided on its own. I simply said "open project" and pointed to the directory. I did *not* say either Maven or sbt.

Comment: If you just opened most probably it's a `maven` project. AFAIK for `sbt` projects needs to be imported not opened directly. You can confirm this by checking your modules. Right click on your project in Project side bar then choose `Open Module Settings`. Then go to `Modules`. If you see some build projects with SBT logo on them your project has the nature of a `sbt` project.

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari Yours is the correct answer. If you care to make a formal answer i will award.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just opened the project (`File` -> `Open` ) most probably it's a maven project.

AFAIK `sbt` projects need to be imported not opened directly.

You can confirm this by checking your modules. Right click on your project in Project side bar then choose `Open Module Settings`. Then go to `Modules`. If you see some build projects with SBT logo on them your project has the nature of a sbt project., if not it's a Maven project.